# I was getting error while running one log4j in netbeans

Tags: java, log4j

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;

public class Log {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log.class);
       PropertyConfigurator.configure("log.properties");
       log.debug("Hello this is a debug message");
       log.info("Hello this is an info message");
   }

}
```

Error is :-
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (log.Log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: What does your log.properties look like? I get no warnings testing with `org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender`

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that it cannot find log4j.properties on your classpath.  Even though you are trying to instantiate your own Configurator, log4j will look for the properties file as part of class loading.

Comment: Can you help how to give path, as i am very new in this concept 
thanks in avance

Comment: Assuming you have defined log4j.properties, there are several ways to do it.  Simplest is to put it in the root directory of where your class files are.  If in a jar file, put it in root of jar file.

Comment: Thanks, can you let me know in netbeans IDE where i have to put log4j.xml file.
inside Source package folder or somewhere else ?
Please help me out :(

Comment: I use Eclipse, not NetBeans, so it would depend on default classpath that it creates for a project.  I usually put it in the src folder, the root folder for my .java files.